# Почему не работает возврат значения по умолчанию?

Tags: jquery

```
var Email = $('#email');

Email.focus(function(){

    if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('defaultValue'))
    {$(this).val('');
    }
});

Email.blur(function() {

    if ($(this).val() == '' ) {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('defaultValue'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Эта же Поповская проблема была :)))

Comment: Тоже ломал голову, что делать.

Comment: да да)именно его)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).val($(this).attr('defaultValue');
---------------------------------------^
```

скобку пропустили: [пруф](http://jsfiddle.net/d4BQx/)

Comment: все равно(

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: делаю копипаст себе в проект, не работает) теряючь с догадках почему

Comment: Firebug или его аналоги вам в помощь

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, вы не отследили DOM loaded:

```
$(function(){
var Email = $('#email');

Email.focus(function(){

    if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('defaultValue'))
    {$(this).val('');
    }
});

Email.blur(function() {

    if ($(this).val() == '' ) {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('defaultValue'));
    }
});
});
```

А что говорит консоль?

Comment: пишет Метка времени: 25.07.2012 15:03:30
Предупреждение: Метод getAttributeNodeNS() является устаревшим. Для его замены используйте метод getAttributeNS().
Источник: http://jtest.ru/
Строка: 0

Comment: Ошибка может быть связанна с тем, что html не валидный (это исключительно мое мнение). Попробуйте не defaultValue, а атрибут data-defaultValue.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это все нужно запихнуть в $(document).ready()

Comment: запихнуто) просто не писал это в вопросе

Comment: если вместо $(this).attr('defaultValue') указывать конкретное значение то все работает

Comment: ну так может в разметке дело? проверьте точно названия атрибутов инпута

Comment: всмысле? конструкция с defaultValue должно возвращать значение по умолчанию. я же говорю что если написать конкретно например $(this).val() == 'aaa@bbb.ru' то все работает, а если меняnm на свойство defaultValue то отказывается

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему поставив `prop` вместо `attr`. Видимо в уроках устаревшая информация была